# Unity quick launch icon opens another program icon on program start

Tags: unity, launcher

I prepared a custom .desktop file for my chromium browser that loads a different user profile. When ever i click the icon now it open the browser, but also uses a new icon on the launcher bar (not locked to the launcher). Is there any way to tell the program to keep connected to the first icon?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Second Browser
Exec=chromium-browser --user-data-dir="/home/patrick/bin/chrome-profiles/second"
TryExec=chromium-browser
Icon=/home/patrick/.local/share/applications/icons/browser.png
MimeType=text/html;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy way to accomplish exactly what I am trying to do:

```
StartupWMClass=www.domainname.com__some_path
```

will group all windows of the same domain and/or path. You can find out the WM_CLASS by executing the following command on the shell and clicking the window you want to find the class out for:

```
xprop WM_CLASS
```

This way you can have more than one Chromium-browser entry on your launchbar and the entries stay grouped together.

Comment: what was the line in your case?

Comment: StartupWMClass=mail.google.com_mail

Answer (score 1):

NO, not easily.

This will often occur after an update, where **Ubuntu** / Unity no longer thinks this is the exact same application.  I also often get this with LibreOffice.

---

***Suggested workarounds:***

**(1.)** Lock the icon that opens to the Unity bar, and remove (detach) the other.

**OR**

**(2.)** Recreate your custom launcher, based on the default launcher.  See my posting: [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)